# What is the material used to make Falcon's wings?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, falcon, the-falcon-and-the-winter-soldier

In the new MCU series *The Falcon and The Winter Soldier*, Sam Wilson performs many stunts with his wings and restricts bullets. What is the metal or material which is used to make his wings?

Comment: The suit in F&TWS is an upgraded version (or at least painted version) to the previous one and we have no information on it really. We don't even know that much on the initial one (if it is different). Also note that the "initial" wings have also been seen doing similar stunts.

Comment: If you have to ask, the answer is "vibranium"...

Comment: It's comicbookimaginationarium

Comment: The generic term for such a material is Unobtainium, by the way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtainium. The only thing that can resist it, is plot armor.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'm aware this is somewhat tongue in cheek but I'd like to point out that the majority of the wings aren't made from metal. Also they were made before proper contact was made with Wakanda so they wouldn't have had access to Vibranium anyway.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'll answer as best I can with the information available to me at the moment and that is simply that we don't know. The [wiki page](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/EXO-7_Falcon) for the EXO-7 Falcon wings says *"impact-resistant carbon fiber material"* but offers no citation to back this up. There isn't really anything in the films themselves as to what they could be. We do see the file on the EXO-7 Falcon in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* but only the cover as far as I know.

The only indication we get is Peter's educated guess but Sam doesn't answer him as, y'know, they're in the middle of a fight:

> **Peter Parker:** Oh god. Hey buddy, I think you lost this! Those wings carbon fiber?
>
> **Sam Wilson:** Is this stuff coming out of you?
>
> **Peter Parker:** That would explain the rigidity-flexibility ratio, which, gotta say, that's awesome, man.
>
> **Sam Wilson:** I don't know if you've been in a fight before but there's usually not this much talking.
>
> <sub>*Captain America: Civil War*</sub>

There is some more information in *Marvel's Captain America: The Winter Soldier: The Art of the Movie*. Essentially the wings are made of some metal for the frame, a "sailboat kind of material" and tines for support, as Josh Nizza says below. However, precisely what materials the suit is supposed to be is never stated.

> "We did a lot of explorations of what his wings would look like," Nizzi explains. "Are they a glider suit? Are they mechanical wings? How bird-like are they? Do they look like wings from an airplane? There were tons of different explorations. Ultimately, what was decided on was a mix of different levels of flexibility in the armature, almost with a sailboat kind of material. And then we added some additional tines in there, but the big reference was sails from sailboats."
>
> [...]
>
> "The wings are a mix of different materials, so they look like the could be layered," Nizzi continues. "They needed to be really thin to look like they could collapse into his backpack. The actual armature is very small, and the fabric-like material is stretched over other stuff and has different levels of rigidity."
>
> <sub>*Marvel's Captain America: The Winter Soldier: The Art of the Movie*</sub>

It's worth noting that you can certainly see the different materials of the wings when you look closely into them. Note that the second image is the same suit but just repainted as far as I can tell from when he joins the Avengers.

[image: Close up on the Falcon firing his guns with the original wings spread] [image: Sam's repainted wings as he lands in the New Avengers HQ]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

---

Since this question was asked and the season has now ended we have seen that Sam now has a new suit and set of wings courtesy of the Wakandans. Given that they are Wakandan made we can be reasonably sure that they are made at least partially from Vibranium.

[image: Sam in his new suit with the wings spread]

---

I think it is worth noting that the EXO-7 Falcon wings seen in *Falcon and the Winter Soldier* are clearly an upgraded version at the very least. The main supporting structure and the overall shape is different, however, it isn't clear if this is a completely new suit or just an altered one. What we can sort of make out though is that the wings still consist of metal supporting frame, fabric-like material for the most part with supporting tines throughout. As such the overall materials used in the construction don't seem to have changed.

[image: Sam hovers in the air with his new wings outspread]

---

Lastly, I just want to point out that we do see Sam performing similar acts with his original wings as he does with the new ones. He uses them as a shield a couple of times to stop incoming projectiles so the strength doesn't seem to have changed.

[image: Sam uses his wings to shield his back as he sets off an explosion behind himself]

Answer (score 15):

In the original comic-books, the Falcon's wings were made of titanium (for strength) and mylar (for lightness). It's certainly possible that this carried over into the films.

> Weapons: The Falcon is able to fly by
> means of his jet-powered glider wings which
> extend beneath his arms from his wrists to
> his waist. Made of **lightweight titanium ribbing and mylar**, the wings are covered with
> wafer-thin, high efficiency solar power receptors which convert sunlight into electricity that powers an array of miniature high-speed electro-turbine fans.
>
> <sub><sup>[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Vol 1 4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_1_4)</sup></sub>

---

Purely for the record, the most recent incarnation of Falcon's suit incorporates [hard-light holographic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwdxIUeMrSM) tech.

> His current costume is synthetic stretch fabric lined with protective
> steel alloy mesh and **housing a pair of holographic, solid-light (“hard
> light”) wings stored within an electronic backpack.** The backpack’s
> mentally controlled systems allow Sam to dissipate and re-form the
> wings almost instantly at will. The hard-light wings are faster and
> more maneuverable than his original wings.
>
> <sub><sup>[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A-Z Vol 1 4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A-Z_Vol_1_4)</sup></sub>